# regex pattern - quote function

Tags: php, regex

I found this regex on a forum:

```
"/\+?\)\)(=.+?,.+?)?\](.+?)\[\/quote\](?!((.*?)\[\/quote\]))/s"
```

The regex should be able to extract data from a string. I will give you an example:

```
<?php
$string = ‘[quote=username]bla bla bla bla[/quote]’;

preg_match("/\+?\)\)(=.+?,.+?)?\](.+?)\[\/quote\](?!((.*?)\[\/quote\]))/s", $string, $match, null, 0);

print_r($match);
```

… However, nothing is returned to $match. I am guessing that there is something wrong with the regex, since it should return both ‘username’ and ‘bla bla bla bla’.
I am going to use the function for a quote function in a forum.

Thanks in advance,
fischer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use something a little easier to read...

```
$string = '[quote=username]bla bla bla bla[/quote]';

preg_match('/\[quote=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/quote\]/', $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

#### Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => [quote=username]bla bla bla bla[/quote]
    [1] => username
    [2] => bla bla bla bla
)
```

[See it on IDEone](http://ideone.com/mSFTS).

I assume your string will contain more than that - hence lazy quantifiers and no beginning and end anchors.

Also, make sure your string is delimited by single (`'`) or double quotes (`"`), not backticks. Backticks are syntactic sugar for a [`shell_exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) call.

#### Update

I'll try and decipher your original regex for you...

```
/\+?\)\)(=.+?,.+?)?\](.+?)\[\/quote\](?!((.*?)\[\/quote\]))/s


/  -> start delimiter
\+? -> optional '+'
\) -> literal ')'
\) -> literal ')'
(=.+?,.+?)? -> not sure the reason for this (enlighten me?)
\] -> match literal ']'
(.+?) -> match one or more characters ungreedy
\[\/quote\] -> match ending '[/quote]'
(?! -> negative lookahead
((.*?) -> match 0 or more characters ungreedy
\[\/quote\] -> match ending '[/quote]'
))
/ -> ending delimiter
s -> case insensitive flag
```

Comment: this will not handle nested quotes: in `[quote]bla [quote] bla[/quote][/quote]` this will match `[quote]bla [quote] bla[/quote]`

Comment: @user576875 Well the OP could modify the regex until it was almost unreadable, or write some other form of parser that handles all this properly. I'm going to try and decipher that regex above :)

Answer (score 1):

The following regex should work:

```
$string = '[quote=username]bla [quote=a]bla[/quote] bla bla[/quote]';

preg_match('~(
        \[quote=(?<username>.*?)\] # match [quote=username]
        (?<quote>(?:.*?(?0))*.*?) # match text inside [quote], including nested quotes
        \[\/quote\] # match closing [/quote]
)~xs', $string, $matches);

if (isset($matches['quote'])) {
        echo "quoted: " . $matches['quote'] . "\n";
        echo "username: " . $matches['username'] . "\n";
}
```

It also allows nested quotes.